# Dynamically create Service Calls within UI API

Tags: vb.net, sdk, sapb1

Using SAP B1 9.2 PL09, in Service Contract, we need a user to be able to automatically create service calls depending on the frequency of the contract (which is Preventative Maintenance contract). So let's say the user select "Monthly" (from a UDF I have created), system needs to create 12 service calls when adding the new Service Contract.

I already have an AddOn who add some controls in the Service Contract form. Can I add DI API code in the addon?? Or is there any easier way to do what we need to do??

thanks for your time and help

Comment: Yes, you can add DI API code in your Addon and that's the correct approach for creating new documents in B1, either in a UI Addon or a batch process.

Comment: thanks for pointing out it's the best approach. I'll do it that way.